# Dragend event not firing in Chrome when an iframe is moved in drop function

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, drag-and-drop

**EDIT: This is now fixed in Chrome 72!**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r8wxpujg/1/

On every complete drag-and-drop operation, I expect a `dragstart` and a `dragend` event to be fired on the element being dragged. The demo linked to above demonstrates this effect by counting the `dragstart` and `dragend` events. When the image is being moved around by the drag-and-drop operations the `dragstart` and `dragend` events fire and the counter increments as expected. When the button is clicked so that instead of moving the image around, an `iframe` is moved around instead, the `dragend` counter stops incrementing, indicating that the `dragend` event is never fired.

Somehow in Chrome, the moving of an `iframe` in the DOM cancels the `dragend` event from being fired.

I have tested this in Firefox and IE11, and both have the expected behavior when moving `iframe`s.

I have researched this for a couple of days now and have been unable to find any information so I wanted to ask if anyone has run into this before or if someone has a solution. Could this be a bug in Chrome? Or am I just missing something.

**EDIT**: This is a confirmed bug in chromium, the bug report can be found here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737691 .

See Paul's answer below for a workaround until the issue gets fixed.

Comment: I am also seeing this.  Sorry it's not more helpful.  Just found it, and searched for "dragend" and "iframe", and found this.  Maybe this is a recently introduced bug?

Comment: Ah, i see you filed a chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737691&q=dragend&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue in Chrome/Mac. Was going crazy trying to trace it until I found your post. Thanks for reporting it and hopefully it gets squashed soon.

Comment: I've changed your sample a little: https://jsfiddle.net/r8wxpujg/5/. The frame or images changes it's parent every 5 sec. If you drag and drop between "transitions" - it is OK, no matter iframe is moved or image. But if a "transition" occurs between dragstart and dragend - in case if iframe transition drop event is failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now in Chrome 72.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that this is a [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737691) and I don't have a solution for that. But in some cases you could work around the bug by delaying the iframe move until the drag events are done. It works in [this fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpwinn/5Lrsf34L/). Just replace your

```
if(element.id === 'div1drag') {
    document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(item);
}
else if(element.id === 'div2drag') {
    document.getElementById('div2').appendChild(item);
}
```

with this

```
if(element.id === 'div1drag') {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(item);
    }, 0)
}
else if(element.id === 'div2drag') {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('div2').appendChild(item);
    }, 0)
}
```

Also, Thanks for reporting that bug. It was driving me crazy today.

Comment: I accepted your answer for providing a workaround. Hopefully the Chromium team will fix this soon and I can update this.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround which I used was to, instead of listening on the `dragEnd` event, I listened for the `drop` event, which served my needs adequately, though it might not work for everyone.

Comment: what about when you hit escape to cancel the drop?